# Does AWS Application load balancer actually support compression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

My front-end code talks directly to the Application load balancer for my backend (using JSON over HTTPS).

I'm  starting to retrieve more than trivial amount of data - so I thought I should work out what changes I had to make to support compressing the HTTP data.

I've come across a few posts stating that AWS load balancer compression is broken.

Example: https://medium.com/@sanjay.rajak/why-i-replaced-aws-elastic-load-balancer-to-haproxy-load-balancer-72207fad2d96

But as far as I can tell from the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=compression&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=Elastic%20Load%20Balancing&this_doc_guide=Application%20Load%20Balancers&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=Elastic%20Load%20Balancing&facet_doc_guide=Application%20Load%20Balancers) - ELB / ALB etc. don't actually support compression at all.

As a work-around, I can direct my backend calls through Cloudfront  or API-gateway to get compression if I want - that's probably even the "right" way to do it, given that these services can also do some caching of requests, etc.

But before I go messing about with these other services - is it true that AWS load balancers don't support compression at all?

Comment: They don't *implement* compression but this does raise a question of whether they are also modifying headers in an unexpected/undocumented way, or whether the author of that post has overlooked something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Layer 4 Classic (ELB) or Network Load balancer. Since the Layer 4 load balancer is load balancing TCP traffic, ELB won't touch your HTTP headers or response.

[Network Load Balancer FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/faqs/)

Comment: Oh - wow, you're right.  I guess because I started with cloudfront, I just assumed that ALB would do the compression for me.  You're right, with the EC2 server doing the compression, the ALB passes along the compressed content just fine.

Answer (score 16):

I just tested this with an application running behind an Application Load Balancer. With gzip compression enabled on the server, the browser receives gzipped resources. The ALB correctly passes along the `content-encoding: gzip` HTTP header. Note that with ALB you also get HTTP/2 support which further reduces the time it takes for browsers to load your website's files.

I think that article you linked is incorrect, or out of date, or maybe it's an issue specific to Classic ELBs.

Comment: Can you please share the exact steps that you used for this setup? In my case, I am also not getting gzip compression with ALB. I'm using NodeJS frontend and Java backend.

Comment: @NeronJoseph it's dependent on the configuration of your backend server, the ALB just passes it along. If you try accessing the EC2 server directly, do you get a gzipped response?